# include_directory inheritance within CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have 2 projects L and A in CMake, say L is a library and A an application depending on L.

The folders hierarchy looks like:

- A

  - CMakeLists.txt + headers + src
- L

  - CMakeLists.txt + headers + src
  - subL

    - headers + src files

Now, in terms of include directories I understand I need to specify **subL** in **L/CMakeLists.txt/include_directories()**, so the other files within L can reference the include files simply with a **#include "mySubLHeaderFile.h"** or **#include < mySubLHeaderFile.h>**.

Now if I want to reference a header file from **subL** within a file from the **A** project and be able to reference this **subL** file simply with a **#include "mySubLHeaderFile.h"** or **#include < mySubLHeaderFile.h>**, I have noticed I need to re-specify **subL** in **A/CMakeLists.txt/include_directories()**. Is this a normal behavior? Aren't the **include_directories()** inherited from the depended project?

------ EDIT 1 -------

Note that I have a top level CMakeLists.txt above A and L.

Comment: Do you have a top level CMakeLists.txt, above A and L?

Comment: I do indeed have a top level CMakeLists.txt, over A and L. Just modified the post to reflect this.

Comment: I'm unsure about this, but I think you can put an include_directories in that top-level file, so that all subfolders have access.

Comment: And do you have any idea of the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the standard behavior for CMake's `include_directories` command.  If you want properties to propagate to dependents, use the [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/target_include_directories.html) command that became standard with version 3.  Specifically, locations with headers that are needed by client code should be in the `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` section.  If SubL also needs to include headers there, use `PUBLIC`.  Look at the whole family of `target_*` commands for property propagation to dependents.